# ADO select statement with full text search with SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-injection

The database that I am connecting to has a table with a Full Text Search index.  This works correctly.

```
select * from MyTable where contains(*, 'value')
```

In WPF if I send that exact command down it works.  However `value` is not hard coded it is something an user types in so it needs to be protected for SQL injection.  The issue is that in doing so it does not return results.  Here is my code;

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string ConString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=sa;Password=amazingSecurePassword;";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            string sqlCMD = "select * from MyTable where contains(*, @s1)"
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCMD, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCMD, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@s1", "value"));

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                //Error logic
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Edit:  @Mike comment worked.  Change the SqlDbType.NVarChar fixed the issue

Comment: Please don't add tags that have nothing to do with your questions. I removed the WPF tag.

Comment: @Sheridan but I am doing this in WPF.  How does this have nothing to do with WPF?

Comment: @sasha_gud sorry, the code is from a method, sqlCMD is what is passed.  I copied and pasted the "string sqlCMD" line in the wrong place.  It is now fixed

Comment: Regardless of your chosen application technology, *this problem* has no direct relation to WPF at all.

Comment: If possible, fire up SQL Trace to see the query that is created behind the scenes. See if the SQL code is passing in the variable correctly. Also, have you attempted to set the `SQlDbType` to `NVarChar` during the creation of the [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Mike the problem was in fact NVarChar!  If you post this as an answer I will mark it as the answer.  Heck copy past the post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the above comment, setting the `SQlDbType` to `NVarChar` during the creation of the `SqlParameter` helps the CLR determine the right data type. More info about [the SqlParameter constructor at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y.aspx).